# Comparing arrays with source questions and user answers

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to realize simple testing application. And I ran into a problem. I have two arrays. The first is an array with the initial questions, the second array is the answers of users. And now I need to count the number of correct answers. I wrote the following code. I wonder: how optimal is it and, if it's bad, how to optimize it?
I tried to change the "filter" to "find", but this did not affect the execution time of the code.

```js
const questions = [
 {
  questionId: 1,
  question: 'question?',
  answers: [
   { value: '1', right: true },
   { value: '2', right: false },
   { value: '3', right: false },
   { value: '4', right: false },
  ],
 },
 {
  questionId: 2,
  question: 'question?',
  answers: [
   { value: '1', right: false },
   { value: '2', right: false },
   { value: '3', right: false },
   { value: '4', right: true },
  ],
 },
 {
  questionId: 3,
  question: 'question?',
  answers: [
   { value: '1', right: false },
   { value: '2', right: true },
   { value: '3', right: false },
   { value: '4', right: false },
  ],
 },
 {
  questionId: 4,
  question: 'question?',
  answers: [
   { value: '1', right: true },
   { value: '2', right: false },
   { value: '3', right: false },
   { value: '4', right: false },
  ],
 },
 {
  questionId: 5,
  question: 'question?',
  answers: [
   { value: '1', right: false },
   { value: '2', right: false },
   { value: '3', right: true },
   { value: '4', right: false },
  ],
 },
]

const answersFromUser = [
 {
  questionId: 1,
  value: '1',
 },
 {
  questionId: 2,
  value: '1',
 },
 {
  questionId: 3,
  value: '1',
 },
 {
  questionId: 4,
  value: '1',
 },
 {
  questionId: 5,
  value: '1',
 },
]

const createObj = (questionId, value, right) => {
 return { questionId, value, right }
}

const checkAnswers = (questionsArr, answersArr) => {
 return answersArr.map(answer => {
  const currentQuestion = questionsArr.filter(
   question => question.questionId === answer.questionId
  )

  const currentAnswer = currentQuestion[0].answers.filter(
   answerInCurrentQuestion => answerInCurrentQuestion.value === answer.value
  )[0]

  return createObj(
   answer.questionId,
   currentAnswer.value,
   currentAnswer.right
  )
 })
}

const countRightAnswers = answers => {
 return answers.filter(answer => answer.right).length
}

const countWrongAnswers = answers => {
 return answers.filter(answer => !answer.right).length
}

console.log(checkAnswers(questions, answersFromUser))
console.log("Right Answers " + countRightAnswers(checkAnswers(questions, answersFromUser)))
console.log("Wrong Answers " + countWrongAnswers(checkAnswers(questions, answersFromUser)))
```

Comment: Can there ever be more than one correct answer for a question? Do you need all the info in the answer objects you create? You could make things a lot simpler if you just had an array for correct answers and another for the user's answers.

Comment: No, there can only be one correct answer. No, not all information. Need a answer number and know whether it is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is not much of a code review answer, but I don't have time for more right now :(

Here's a stripped down version using only arrays for answers, with indexes (zero to four) as the question numbers. Essentially, it seems like much of your object structures aren't needed at all.

```javascript
const correctAnswers = [1,4,2,1,3]

const userAnswers = [1,1,1,1,1]

const countRightAnswers = answers => answers.filter((a, i) => a == correctAnswers[i]).length

const indexOfRightAnswers = answers => answers.map((a, i) => a == correctAnswers[i] ? i : -1).filter(i => i > -1)

console.log(countRightAnswers(userAnswers))
console.log(indexOfRightAnswers(userAnswers))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZDBCsIwDIbve4ocW@gGUw8iTPEJBK9jh1K7LVLb0XbTt5/MWdlUGLn8JB9//uTKO@6ExcbH3bbvhdHOgzDWSuGP2t2ldZBBnrINW7GUrYsoGpnWSTsD3vUBhGm1P2NVT3x4UPsgkxKVl5YQzgDpawBZ9pUgx4ImSurK18Ed9UU@TuWy/403i@ZwAIQdxCkNcXCAEfZDb1xplEyUqcjPWWTyCUpn7J@Qc7rvnw)